# Is it possible to store data for an offline-first native app that syncs with a web version without a backend?

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I'm working on a somewhat typical notes app that I plan to create with React Native. Since the usage involves a lot of typing, it makes sense that there should also be a web version that users could open on their desktop.

Now, if the app was mobile-only I was planning to store the data locally using SQLite and let users back it up to Google Drive or Dropbox if they want to transfer to a new install. This becomes a bit messy once a web app comes into the picture, since now I would need to store the data on a server and sync the native as well as web version with it. Is it still possible to use a cloud storage method in this situation or do I have to go all the way and create a backend with a database, authentication, and a REST API for this to be viable?

Edit: I have not used firebase before but it looks like it was meant for something like this, could someone correct me if I'm wrong? It looks like there's a driver for offline sync with react native too (https://rnfirebase.io/database/offline-support)

Another one I found is Realm Sync (https://www.mongodb.com/realm/mobile/sync)

Comment: Why would you want to use a local database for a note app? I suggest you use plain files (a folder for your resources). Users like that, it's open. Same on the server. File system based is the way to go. I would use your app. And markdown please. Go!  :-)

Comment: @MartinMaat: how would using plain files simplify the requirement of editing the same data pool from a mobile app as well as from a Web app?

Comment: @DocBrown It probably would not, you would have to take care of that yourself using lock files. I was not providing an answer, I just wanted to provide some input as a potential user. I use a note app a lot and this is one thing I would have liked to be different.

Comment: @DocBrown: it's reasonable for users to use their own online storage (e.g. Google Drive) for e.g. their personal notes made in the app, which would then be accessible from anywhere and preclude the issue at hand. I use this for several webtools (e.g. draw.io). Comparatively, it's not reasonable for users to have to spin up their own db.

Comment: @Flater: I think your comment is off-track. The alternatives discussed here were an SQlite database (which would also be a file stored in the personal online storage) vs. *plain* files. And yes, it is absolutely common to have each user their own SQlite database. For example, my Firefox browser here uses for for storing its configuration.

Comment: ... the issue in this question arises when the same user uses his mobile phone to change some notes locally, to write it back later to a central storage, and a web browser to change their notes as well. This already requires to replicate data on a small scale, and the OP is asking if their is a small-scale solution for the replication/synchronization issue without setting up an own application server.

Comment: Ok, so the mobile app can store it's data locally.  And the web app needs to be able to access that data so it can edit it.  That means the web app needs to be able to connect directly to the phone so the phone needs to host a server that can be connected to.  If you can't store the data on the web what other choice do you have?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to do the peer 2 peer thing if both the mobile and the desktop are on the same wifi network because then you don't have to worry about all the infrastructure between the mobile and the desktop.  Maybe something like this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/what-is-wifi-direct-in-windows-10-and-how-to-use-it/ https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/wifi-direct-vs-bluetooth-use-sharing-data-windows-8/

Comment: In general the easiest way is with some kind of backend. Why: Because you can use the internet connection which is the most simple already available connection method. All other connection methods require shared wifi / bluetooth etc. which needs some setup. Also user experience: They will expect a seamless sync without thinking about the connections -> The internet. You can use a standard hosted backend like Firebase or the others mentioned. That won't make the the biggest difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/) as a frontend for SQlite. This would allow to use SQlite like any web enabled database, so your web app can use the same format like your local app.

Node-RED let´s you create REST-api´s very simple, so you can add some SQL-security to prevent users from hacking your database.

I´m just a bit unsure if you can access SQlite somewhere in a data storage, so maybe using different user accounts gets a bit tricky. But it´s definitively worth a try.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding this answer, but how does this answer the question *"Is it still possible to use a cloud storage method in this situation [without setting up a database, authentication, and a REST API]"*?

Comment: @DocBrown I suppose it doesn't have to be restricted to a cloud storage method. What I'm looking for is basically something that saves me the hassle of creating and maintaining a backend for some simple data sync across devices (since all it does is store a user's personal data) that could maybe be self hosted if required. So far firebase is the closest thing I found

Comment: Node-RED gives you access to SQlite via a REST api, so you can store the SQlite file anywhere but run it like a normal database. *In some cases this I found this option very convenient. Thought this could help in your case.*